# Alternativa ao TransactionScope

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transações

Estou usando **Entity Framework** (versão 4.4) em um projeto **AspNet MVC** com **.NET Framework** um pouco antigo (versão 4.0) e **SQL Server**.

Não tenho acesso ao servidor onde está hospedado a aplicação, e de vez em quando ele sofre algumas migrações para outros servidores, sendo assim fui orientado a evitar usar técnicas que façam com que seja necessário algum recurso extra (que não esteja por padrão).

Estou desenvolvendo uma funcionalidade na aplicação que precisa de uma transação, mas por padrão o EF fecha a conexão na chamada do `SaveChanges()`, e assim recebo uma `exception` ao tentar fazer qualquer nova requisição através do meu objeto `Entities` recebo a seguinte exception:

> O provedor subjacente falhou em Open.

Tentei então instanciar meu `context` em momentos distintos para cada alteração, mas o mesmo erro persiste.

```
using(TransactionScope ts = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope())
{
    var teste1 = new Teste();
    using (var context = new MyEntities())
    {
        teste1.Nome = "Teste1";
        context.Add(teste1);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    // Até aqui tudo está funcionando bem!

    using (var context = new MyEntities())
    {
        //Erro nessa linha!
        var usuario = context.User.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserId == ViewSessionContext.UserId);

        if(usuario != null)
        {
           var teste2 = new FilhoTeste();
           teste2.Nome = "FilhoTeste";
           teste2.TesteId = teste1.Id;
           teste2.UserId = usuario.Id;
           teste2.Add(teste2);
           context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    ts.Complete();

}
```

Seria possível usar uma transação sem precisar habilitar o [DTC](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753510.aspx)?

Tentei também forçar a abertura da conexão, mas recebi o mesmo erro!

Fontes de pesquisa:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475008/mssql-error-the-underlying-provider-failed-on-open
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794707/why-doesnt-transactionscope-work-with-entity-framework
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794364/how-do-i-use-transactionscope-in-c

Comment: O que é `DatabaseEntityModel` e qual a necessidade dele?

Comment: desculpe, foi erro meu na hora de editar o exemplo. Fiz a correção na pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

Não há necessidade de abrir dois contextos dentro de um escopo de transação. Faça isso usando o mesmo contexto:

```
using (var ts = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope())
{
    using (var context = new MyEntities())
    {
        var teste1 = context.Teste.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Id = 1);
        teste1.Nome = "Teste1";
        context.Entry(teste1).State = EntityState.Modified;

        var teste2 = context.Teste.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Id = 2);
        teste2.Nome = "Teste2";
        context.Entry(teste2).State = EntityState.Modified;

        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    ts.Complete();
}
```

O raciocínio é análogo quando há dependência entre objetos:

```
using (var ts = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope())
{
    var teste1 = new Teste();
    using (var context = new MyEntities())
    {
        teste1.Nome = "Teste1";
        context.Add(teste1);
        context.SaveChanges();

        var usuario = context.User.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserId == ViewSessionContext.UserId);

        if(usuario != null)
        {
           var teste2 = new FilhoTeste();
           teste2.Nome = "FilhoTeste";
           teste2.TesteId = teste1.Id;
           teste2.UserId = usuario.Id;
           teste2.Add(teste2);

           context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    ts.Complete();    
}
```

Comment: No seu caso você está usando o SaveChanges para os dois objetos criados, no meu caso eu dependo do Objeto1 criado para poder criar o Objeto2. Vou reeditar meu exemplo na pergunta.

Comment: Editado! Acho que agora deu pra dar uma ideia melhor do meu contexto...

Comment: Já editei a resposta. É a mesma coisa, quase.

Comment: O seu DTC está habilitado?

Comment: Normalmente vem habilitado por padrão. Só não vem em máquinas muito antigas.

Comment: Infelizmente este é o meu caso. O DTC está desabilitado e não tenho como habilita-lo...